# Error updating a cell with data from Parse

Tags: uitableview, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

In Parse I have a class called "Shouts", with a string value called "wall"

I need to see how many "Shouts" I have in every "wall" using a Label inside a cell of my tableview

In my TableviewCell I have:

```
@IBOutlet var newWallLabel: UILabel!  // the name of the wall (cell is working)
@IBOutlet var shoutCounter: UILabel!  // using this label I want to show the number of objects I have in my "Shouts" class with the same newWallLabel (that is my "wall" String in my Shouts Class)
```

In my TableView I'm using countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. With println works, it show me the number of value I have for this "testing" String in my Shout class in Parse. But what I need is actually to use whatever text will have my newWallLabel UILabel

So I've been trying for a while to connect this "(count)" to my shoutCounter label, creating in my TableView:

```
  var counter:UILabel!
```

then this var inside the func that load all the data of the wall

```
       var countShout = PFQuery(className: "Shouts")
    countShout.whereKey("wall", containsString: "testing")
            countShout.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (count, _) -> Void in
                if count == 0 {
                    println("No Shouts")
                } else {
                    self.counter.text = "\(count)"
                }
    }
```

then when configuring my cell I've used

```
        cell.shoutCounter.text = counter.text
```

Everything looks fine without errors, but when I build the app it crash with a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" pointing at this string

```
        cell.shoutCounter.text = counter.text
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: Ok, counter is Nil, but why?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on questions yet, but `counter` is nil because you haven't initialized it to any value. If it exist on your storyboard, then it shouldn't be nil. Perhaps you can try to recreate the `IBOutlet`

If you are trying to define the label programmatically, check out the sample code for defining a UILabel.

```
var label:UILabel!
label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
label.text = "I'am a test label"
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

I hope this helps.